# Embedding code block into <asp:Treeview /> block

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to do this:

```
<asp:TreeView id="LinksTreeView"
    Font-Names= "Arial"
    ForeColor="Blue"
    EnableClientScript="true"
    PopulateNodesFromClient="true"  
    OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode"
runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Logista" 
        SelectAction="Expand"  
        PopulateOnDemand="true"
        Value="<% SPContext.Current.Web.Url %>"/>

    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

But Visual studio tells me that code blocks are not supported in this context. Is there any way for doing what I want?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try Value="<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Url %>"/> ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all Embedded Code Block delimiters.